Product of two Dirichlet characters with non-coprime moduli
If I have Dirichlet characters $\chi ,\chi '$ modulo $q,q'$ is there anything useful I can say about the individual characters or moduli if I'm given that $$\chi \chi '=\text { id}_{[q,q']}$$
where the RHS is the principal character modulo the LCM of $q,q'$?
If $\chi ,\chi '$ are primitive then I think it follows that $q=q'$ (and so $\chi '=\overline \chi $) but I'm not sure about the general case.

$[q, q']$ is the LCM of $q$ and $q'$, right?

oh ye sorry will write that in

Just factor the characters according to the prime power decomposition of q and q', and read off the information prime by prime.

I'm not sure that gives me anything in general. If the characters are primitive, I can read off information that forces $q=q'$, and similarly if $(q,q')=1$ I can read off that the characters have to be the identity. But for general characters I don't seem to be able to say anything like that. (I may well be missing something though).

$\overline{\chi}$ and $\chi'$ are the same as characters modulo $[q,q']$, hence they are induced by the same primitive character modulo a divisor of $(q,q')$. And vice versa.

awww it's annoying i'm such an idiot... thanks for (again) solving my questions:))

(...specifically (q,q'), not just a divisor of (q,q')?...)

@tomos I fixed this, thank you! (Another way to fix this is to omit the word "primitive". So "induced by the same character modulo $(q,q')$" is equally fine.)

i think we both may have missed something, but by all means i may/probably be wrong. have i missed something in my answer below?

@tomos Let $\chi^$ be a primitive Dirichlet character modulo $q^$. For any multiples $q$ and $q'$ of $q^$, let $\chi$ be the mod $q$ character induced by $\overline{\chi^}$, and let let $\chi'$ be the mod $q'$ character induced by $\chi^$. Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ be arbitrary. If $n$ is coprime with $[q,q']$, then $\chi(n)\chi'(n)=\overline{\chi^(n)}\chi^*(n)=1$. Otherwise, $\chi(n)=0$ or $\chi'(n)=0$, whence $\chi(n)\chi'(n)=0$. This shows that $\chi\chi'$ is the principal character mod $[q,q']$. So your conclusion $q=q'$ is not OK. I think my conclusion (in my response above) is OK.

hmm, ok, i'll delete my post
